# What ways are available for me to query my SQL Server relational database from Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have been looking at the Microsoft examples and most use Entity Framework. However it seems overkill for when I need to make a quick connection. Gets some data from a report and the return it to my web page. It also seems like it is difficult to compose such things as complex SQL that might require a multi-table join and some input parameters.

So what other options are available?

Comment: You can use ado if you do not like  Entity Framework, datareader is extremely quick and with it you can fill your lists or your datatables. Also with .net i believe you can handle situation easier from sql, you can debug them easier.

Comment: What is the "from sql" solution you are suggesting? Also some parts of my application already use EF but I have noticed that doing complex stuff is not so easy. I'm not looking for an alternative. Just some other way to connect to the DB.

Comment: Personally i am using datareader (simple and quick) to fill my class. Datareader fills from sql command. So in command text you can write what ever sql you want or procedure. So once you have your data .net, you can manage them very easy.

Comment: DataReader - SqlDataReader - is the ONLY way - andthing else is built on top of it ;) And the answer is opinionated - for examlple we use EF everywhere in my company unless there are good reasons, regardless how trivial the project. And your "complex" is our easy - if we refactor the mapping we get compile errors, not runtime errors because the SQL does not match reality anymore.

Comment: @TomTom - "DataReader - SqlDataReader - is the ONLY way - andthing else is built on top of it ;)".  Was that your answer or were you referring to a comment someone else made? If you had a requirement to do a three table join with a where clause and some parameters doing a select for each table and it was just for a report that had no functionality then would you still use EF? What I noticed was that EF tends to bring in other entities also. Have you experienced that or is it some problem I have. Even with lazy loading off it seems to bring in data from foreign keys.

Comment: @SamanthaJ - yes. As long as I do not use a query builder I always use either EF or another LINQ provider because I really prefer the compiler telling me my query is crap after a field change over a runtime error report. EF and other tools are perfectly capable of not bringin in entities. For EF it is ismple - do not ask for an entity, but project into a non-entity (Select (x=>new {}) and no entity will be loaded. I do use EF even for larger data analysis, although there calling SP's and using views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a quick way to connect to your datasrouce you can look into some micro ORM-frameworks:

https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

https://github.com/robconery/massive

http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/

These are all tiny libraries that allow you to write your own SQL but still help you (a bit) with mapping the results to classes.

Comment: I am surprised at your answer, after reading the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655509/what-ways-are-available-for-me-to-query-my-sql-server-relational-database-from-w/22655725?noredirect=1#comment34516577_22655725) you posted on mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we do for our reports app that fetches data using Web Api and SQL.

**1. Stored Procedures with EF**

Since you mention you need to fetch data that might require a multi-table join, best approach here would be to use Stored Procedures to get that data. Import that Stored Procedure to the EntityFramework.

**2. Service Layer Class & AutoMapper**

Now create a similar object that will map to the Data Layer's object that will be returned from the Stored Procedure you just added. To map these two classes we use a mapper called as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). We create two classes because we dont want our web app to directly access the Data Layer classes.

**3. Expose your Web API**

Now this data can be sent from the api to whoever wants to use it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would you propose a three tier architecture with mapping overhead when you don't even know what the requirements are?

Comment: @Kenneth thanks for the downvote. As far as the requirement are concerned he made it clear by mentioning a Report and getting data using complex table joins (correct me if I am wrong). So with these requirement I proposed to use EF and listed out a short explanation for the same.

Comment: I just don't see any valid reasons for a 3-layer approach. There's no business rules involved and you are complicating everything by using mappers and layers and all the stuff you don't need if he just wantsa to query and expose data.

Comment: Why dont you let him decide if it complicating him or not ? Fair enough ? and speaking of complicating things by mentioning about mappers and all, you in your answer too have listed out a mapper - Dapper!

Comment: That's a lot more light weight than 3 layers and a full blown ORM for some simple queries.